# Realm object has values inside, but when I serialise it with GSON, the string contains 0 or empty arrays

Tags: android, json, database, serialization, realm

This is the objects that I have inside my TripStep model:

```
@SerializedName("travel_mode")
private String travelMode;
@SerializedName("moving_time")
private int movingTime;
@SerializedName("moving_distance")
private int movingDistance;
private Polyline polyline;
private String vehicle;
private Route route;
@SerializedName("trip_id")
private int tripId;
@SerializedName("departure_stop")
private TripStop departureStop;
@SerializedName("arrival_stop")
private TripStop arrivalStop;
@PrimaryKey
private int id;
private Transit_details transit_details;
private RealmList<StopInfo> filteredLocations = new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<StopInfo> rawLocations = new RealmList<>();
```

Android studio has generated setters and getters for it, and also I have a constructor with no params, and one with a param for each one of the objects.

If I set something like:

```
 Log.i("","deviations tripstep orig:" + stepOrig.getId() + "");
        Log.i("", "deviations tripstep orig:" + stepOrig.getRoute());
```

It will say:

```
deviations tripstep orig:24930
deviations tripstep orig:Route = [{duration:Duration},{distance:Distance},{arrival_time:null},{end_location:CoordLocation},{start_address:Compagniestraat 49, 1018 HM Amsterdam, Netherlands},{end_address:Stationsplein 3-5, 1012 Amsterdam, Netherlands},{departure_time:null},{start_location:CoordLocation},{steps:RealmList<Step>[11]},{legs:RealmList<Route>[0]}]
```

As you can see, I have values inside.
If I serialize it, will say this:

```
  {"filteredLocations":[],"id":0,"moving_distance":0,"moving_time":0,"rawLocations":[],"trip_id":0}
```

So all my, id, Route, etc will be erased. Why does this happen?
This is my Serialising function:

```
public class JsonUtil {

private static JsonUtil instance;

private Gson gson = null;

private JsonUtil() {
    gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                    return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(RealmObject.class);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .create();
}

public static <T> T jsonToObject(String json, Class<T> toClass) throws Exception {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new JsonUtil();
    }
    return instance.gson.fromJson(json, toClass);
}

public static <T> T jsonToObject(InputStream databaseInputStream, Class<T> toClass) throws Exception {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new JsonUtil();
    }
    return instance.gson.fromJson(new InputStreamReader(databaseInputStream), toClass);
}

public static <T> String objectToJson(Object o, Class<T> toClass) throws Exception {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new JsonUtil();
    }
    return instance.gson.toJson(o, toClass);
}
}
```

PS: It works for other RealmObjects, but this one in particular does not work

Comment: try jackson? Have you checked the annotation are they all correct?

Comment: @Dr.aNdRO YES!!! It works with jackson, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used Jackson instead of using GSON, and the json is serialised how it should be, now.
This is how I do it:

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        TripStepNonRealm tripStepNonRealm = new TripStepNonRealm(stepOrig.getTravelMode(), stepOrig.getRoute(), stepOrig.getVehicle());
        final JSONObject juser = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject tripstep = new JSONObject(mapper.writeValueAsString(tripStepNonRealm));
        juser.put("step", tripstep);
        Log.i("", "deviations updateStep ======= tripstep is: " + tripstep);
        Log.i("","deviations updateStep ======= juser is: " + juser);
```